# Using reduce over a tree in Lisp

Tags: tree, lisp, common-lisp, fold

To fold a flat list in Lisp you use `reduce`:

```
* (reduce #'+ '(1 2 3 4 5))
15
```

But what if I have an arbitrarily complex tree, and I want to apply a function over each of the element? So that fold over `'(1 (2) (3 (4) 5))` would still give `15`? I tried to use `reduce`, but I had to provide a custom function, which kinda defeats the purpose:

```
(defun tree+ (a b)
  (cond ((null b) 0)
        ((atom b) (+ a b))
        (t (+ (tree+ a (car b))
              (tree+ 0 (cdr b))))))

(reduce #'tree+ '(1 (2) (3 (4) 5)) :initial-value 0) ; returns 15
```

Of course I could flatten the list first, but `reduce` is a general function, sometimes you must preserve the structure and order of the original sequence. For example, `map` and `filter` can be implemented with `reduce`. What if I wanted to write an implementation of `my-map`, based on `reduce`, so that:

```
(my-map '1+ '(1 (2 (3) 4) 5)) ; outputs '(2 (3 (4) 5) 6)
```

How to use `reduce` over a tree structure? What is the most generic way to apply a binary function over a tree?

Comment: Flatten the tree first: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Flatten_a_list#Common_Lisp

Comment: @uselpa, see the fix, flattening isn't general

Comment: It's about Scheme, but I've implemented a **treeduce** function in [Counting elements of a list and sublists](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20060772/1281433) that shows how to generalize folds for trees.

Comment: Note that your example `(1 (2 (3) 4) 5)` is not an "integer tree" (some leaves are `nil`), but a "nested integer list".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've provided an implementation of a **treeduce** function in [Counting elements of a list and sublists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20060772/1281433), and although it's for Scheme, the same principles apply here.  Wikipedia, in the [Fold (higher-order function)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)), says:

> In functional programming, fold – also known variously as reduce,
>   accumulate, aggregate, compress, or inject – refers to a family of
>   higher-order functions that analyze a recursive data structure and
>   recombine through use of a given combining operation the results of
>   recursively processing its constituent parts, building up a return
>   value. Typically, a fold is presented with a combining function, a top
>   node of a data structure, and possibly some default values to be used
>   under certain conditions. The fold then proceeds to combine elements
>   of the data structure's hierarchy, using the function in a systematic
>   way.

The list data structure can be described as an algebraic datatype:

```
List ::= Cons(Object, List)
       | Nil
```

When we call reduce with a function a list, we're essentially turning each use of `Cons` into an application of the function, and each use of `Nil` with some constant value.  That is, we take the list

```
Cons(x,Cons(y,Cons(z,Nil)))
```

and turn it into

```
Fn(x,Fn(y,Fn(z,init)))
```

Alternatively, you can imagine `Nil` and `init` as as a zero-argument functions, in which case the list is turned into

```
Fn(x,Fn(y,Fn(z,init())))
```

For trees, we can do the same thing, but it's a little bit more complex.  For a tree, the algebraic datatype is:

```
Tree ::= Node(Tree,Tree)
       | Leaf(Object)
```

To do a reduce for a tree, then, we need *two* functions:  one to replace `Node` and one to replace `Leaf`.  The definition is pretty straightforward, though:

```
TreeReduce(nodeFn,leafFn,tree) =
  case tree of 
    Node(left,right) => nodeFn(TreeReduce(nodeFn,leafFn,left),TreeReduce(nodeFn,leafFn,right)
    Leaf(object) => leafFn(object)
```

In Common Lisp, that's simply:

```
(defun tree-reduce (node-fn leaf-fn tree)
  (if (consp tree)
      (funcall node-fn 
               (tree-reduce node-fn leaf-fn (car tree))
               (tree-reduce node-fn leaf-fn (cdr tree)))
      (funcall leaf-fn 
               tree)))
```

```
(tree-reduce 'cons
             (lambda (x) 
               (if (numberp x) (1+ x) x))
             '(1 (2 3) (4 5 6)))
;=> (2 (3 4) (5 6 7))
```

We can use **tree-reduce** to compute the sum that you asked about:

```
(tree-reduce '+
             (lambda (x)
               (if (null x) 0 x))
             '(1 (2) (3 (4) 5)))
;=> 15
```

The reason that we need all of these **null** guards is that when we're viewing a cons-based structure as a tree, **nil** isn't really anything special.  That is, we could consider the tree (1 (2 . 3) 4 . 5) as well as (1 (2 3) 4 (5)) (which is the same as (1 (2 3 . nil) 4 (5 . nil) . nil), of course).

Answer (score 2):

Common Lisp does not have tree versions of `map` or [`reduce`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_reduce.htm).
In fact, the only tree functions I can remember off-hand are [`tree-equal`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_tree_e.htm) and [`subst`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_substc.htm).

However, it should not be too hard to do something like:

```
(defun reduce-tree (function tree &key (key #'identity))
  (if (atom tree)
      (funcall key tree)
      (funcall function
               (reduce-tree function (car tree) :key key)
               (reduce-tree function (cdr tree) :key key))))
```

try it:

```
> (reduce-tree #'+ '(1 . ((2 . 3) . ((4 . 5) . 6))))
==> 21
> (reduce-tree #'+ '(1 (2) (3 (4) 5)) :key (lambda (x) (or x 0)))
==> 15
```

Comment: Copy-tree also maps over a tree.  I have, possibly just for my own amusement, used nsubst to map over a tree.  (defun sum-tree (tree) (let ((sum 0)) (nsubst nil t tree :test #'(lambda (zip x) (declare (ignore zip)) (when (numberp x) (incf sum x)) nil)) sum))  no doubt I'll be punished in the after life for this.

Comment: Note that this definition **won't** let you do `(reduce-tree '+ tree)`, because the `nil` are elements of the tree (unlike the terminating nil in a list).  it also uses the same function for both elements in the tree and for nodes in the tree.  (It's easy to distinguish which case, because function either gets one argument or two, but fold functions often get one argument for each type, and key already serves to process the elements.  It'd probably be sufficient to do `(if (atom tree) (funcall key tree) …)`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: I think it sums tree leaves just fine.

Comment: @sds It's clearer now that you've added examples that highlight the difference between a tree with `nil` in it and a tree without.   OP's original tree was `'(1 (2) (3 (4) 5))`, and `(reduce-tree '+ '(1 (2) (3 (4) 5)))` won't work there because of the `nil`s in the tree. The second example where the key is `(lambda (x) (or x 0))` shows how to work around that. +1 for the examples, though I'm still of the opinion that it's a bit more elegant to have separate functions for the "constructor";  i.e., a function to replace cons, and a function (the key, really) to be called with the atoms. I think…

Comment: …that the `(funcall function (funcall key tree))` has one more function call that it really needs.  The key function doesn't get used anywhere else, so it can handle the "called with one argument" instead of making function be callable with both one and two args.

Comment: you are right about the leaf handling; note that the OP's tree `(1 (2) (3 (4) 5))` is not really an "integer tree" but rather a "nested integer list"

Answer (score 0):

In addition to developing a `tree-reduce`, a useful exercise is to try to repair your existing code so that it is more generally applicable.

That is, we take what you have:

```
(defun tree+ (a b)
  (cond ((null b) 0)
        ((atom b) (+ a b))
        (t (+ (tree+ a (car b))
              (tree+ 0 (cdr b))))))

(reduce #'tree+ '(1 (2) (3 (4) 5)) :initial-value 0)
```

Note how we are just passing `#'tree+` into `reduce`, and `tree+` is hard-coded for addition. The obvious fix is is to curry the `+` function as a functional argument.

To achieve this, we can very simply transform the bulk your `tree+` into a function that returns a function.

We don't use `lambda`, because then we would need a Y-combinator or other silly hack to handle the recursion, which is much more easily achieved by using `labels` to our function a local name:

```
(defun tree-reducer (binary-func &optional initial-val)
  (labels ((tr-red (a b)
             (cond ((null b) initial-val) 
                   ((atom b) (funcall binary-func a b))
                   (t (+ (tr-red a (car b))
                         (tr-red initial-val (cdr b)))))))
     #'tr-red))
```

Now this is used like this:

```
(reduce (tree-reducer #'+ 0) '(1 (2) (3 (4) 5)) :initial-value 0)  -> 15
```

Unfortunately, the initial value is specified twice, the reason for this being that the function returned by `tree-reducer` takes on some of the responsibility of carrying out the reduce logic!  Note that when we add a level of nesting to the tree and call:

```
(reduce (tree-reducer #'+ 0) '((1 (2) (3 (4) 5))) :initial-value 0) -> 15
```

who is doing the work of producing 15? Not the `reduce` function! All it does is call the function once, with the arguments `((1 (2) ...)))` and `0`, which then does all the work.

Also, the initial-value argument of `tree-reducer` will seriously misbehave if it is not the identity element for the given function (like zero to addition).

```
(reduce (tree-reducer #'+ 0) '(1 (2) (3 (4) 5)) :initial-value 1) -> 16  ;; OK

(reduce (tree-reducer #'+ 1) '(1 (2) (3 (4) 5)) :initial-value 0) -> 20  ;; Whoa!
```