# LISP - adding all atoms from a list (any level)

Tags: lisp, addition

I'm guessing that this should be something that's easily done with LISP (they called it that way for a reason), but I can't wrap my mind around it.

Let's say I have the following list:

> ((1 2 3) (4 (5 6)))

I want to add them all, so the result should be 21

I started easy, trying to add elements from a nice list ( like (1 2 3) ), and I pretty much did it:

```
(defun sum (list)
    (if list
        (+ (car list) (sum (cdr list)))
    0)
)
```

There might be better way of coding that and nicer ways of arranging it, but for now this (almost C-like) indentation style helps me to keep track of my parentheses. And it works.

Unfortunately, it is not good enough for the list in my example. So I tried again:

```
(defun sum (list)
    (cond
        ( (atom (car list)) (+ (car list) (sum (cdr list))) )
        ( (list (car list)) (+ (sum (car list) ) (sum (cdr list))))
    )
)
```

This doesn't just looks like overkill, it is overkill as I get a stack overflow error even for simple examples.

Edit:
I managed to write a working (and not so complex) function:

```
(defun sum (l)
  (cond
    ((null l) 0)
    ((atom (car l)) (+ (car l) (sum (cdr l))))
    ((+ (sum (car l)) (sum (cdr l))))
  )
)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using reduce over a tree in Lisp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24720418/using-reduce-over-a-tree-in-lisp)

Comment: This is a question of how to *reduce* the addition function over the elements of a tree. The duplicate I linked to asks about how to reduce a function over a tree and uses addition as a specific example.

Comment: @Joshua Taylor close, but I was interested in doing this without flattening the list (I managed to do the flattening quite easy while trying to do some other things). Interesting link and examples :)

Comment: @user3002428 flattening is just reducing with `append` and `[]`, as summing is reducing with `+` and `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close. Tweak your first variant:

```
(defun sum (list)
    (if list
        (+ (sum (car list)) (sum (cdr list)))
    0)
)
```

because `(car list)` might itself be a list, not necessarily a number.

So now we have to make *this* work, in case it *is* a number - and not only `car`, but a `cdr` also:

```
(defun sum (list)
    (if (not (listp list))
        ; an obvious result here...
        ...
        ; or else it's a list
        (+ (sum (car list)) (sum (cdr list)))
    0)
)
```

But wait, there really are *three* cases here - a non-empty list, an empty list, and not a list. Amend the code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my code with my attempt to apply your advice and it came out pretty close.

Answer (score 3):

You said:

> There might be better way of coding that and nicer ways of arranging it, but for now this (almost C-like) indentation style helps me to keep track of my parentheses. And it works.

Any modern editor will help you with that. The editor indents and counts parentheses. It's very important that indentation is correctly.

The best way to format your Lisp code is like this:

```
(defun sum (list)
  (if list
      (+ (car list)
         (sum (cdr list)))
    0))
```

The better way to write your function is like this:

```
(defun sum (list)
  (cond ((null list)         0)                     ; termination test first
        ((atom (first list)) (+ (first list)        ; FIRST not CAR
                                (sum (rest list)))) ; REST  not CDR
        (t                   (+ (sum (first list))
                                (sum (rest list))))))
```

A slightly different version:

```
(defun sum (list)
  (if (null list)                     ; termination test first
      0                               ; termination value
    (destructuring-bind (head . tail) ; bind variables
        list                          ; matching with LIST
      (+ (if (atom head)              ; all list elements are numbers
             head
           (sum head))
         (sum tail)))))
```

Comment: Re correct indentation, I notice that Emacs uses "body-indentation" for the else branch of the `if` form, but in the Scheme world it is much more common to indent the else branch flush with the then branch (and Riastradh's style guide supports this). Keen to hear your thoughts on all this.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: the 'flush' version is common ;-) in Common Lisp, also. I use LispWorks and its editor uses this style - though it can be configured differently. This style is also used in Emacs Lisp. IIRC on the Lisp Machine you could cycle between the different indentation variants.