# Undocumented function called rec in Common Lisp source with labels?

Tags: common-lisp

I'm noticing this function called `rec` appear many times in Common Lisp code, but I'm not finding references to what it is actually doing. Could anyone explain to me what it is? For instance, it appears in some code from another question, [How to convert a flat list into a nested tree-like structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24716663/how-to-convert-a-flat-list-into-a-nested-tree-like-structure/24750461#24750461):

```
(defun mimicry (source pattern)
  (labels ((rec (pattern)
             (mapcar (lambda (x)
                       (if (atom x)
                         (pop source)
                         (rec x)))
                     pattern)))
    (rec pattern)))
```

Comment: Show more context please. Give the entire program using it. `rec` might be local or specific to that program.

Comment: If you look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24750461/1565698) you'll see `rec` being used as a local function name in a `labels` form. If you change it to `banana` everywhere it will still work, but `rec` indicates that it's a recursive call. In the case it's tail recursive some uses the name `loop` as well,but it will make `loop` macro unavailbale in the same scope so it's probably more common in Scheme than CL.

Comment: @Sylwester I didn't add much information thinking that 'rec' is a common function used in lisp, but somehow just unwell documented online. I've update my thread with sample code from the example. Could you please tell me what this 'rec' function is, and what it's doing exactly?

Comment: Have a look at [**labels**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_flet_.htm) in the HyperSpec;  it explains what's going on here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`rec` is not a global function in you code unless you define it such yourself. It's an local auxiliary function defined with `labels`.

The special operator [`labels`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_flet_.htm) performs a similar task to `defun` except the bindings are local. It's like you use `defparameter` to make global variables and `let` to make local ones.

```
(labels ((banana (arg1)    ; make function banana
           (+ arg1 arg1)))
  (banana 10))             ; use it
; banana doesn't exist anymore
```

Is the same as:

```
(defun banan (arg1) ; make function banana
  (+ arg1 arg1))
(banana 10)         ; use it
; banana still exists
```

The difference is that banana ceases to exist on the outside of the `labels` while with using `defun` you are infesting your global environment with auxiliary functions. Since functions in `labels` are local you can use common names like `rec`, `loop` and `aux` as their names and they will not contaminate other parts of the code.

There is a similar special operator called `flet` that works the same way but it doesn't include its own function in the local environment inhibiting you from calling your very own function in its body. These are useful too but you seldom call them `rec` since `rec` implies it's something *recursive*.

This is not a CL restriction but coding style. I do use the name `rec` and `loop` often in Scheme programming (another Lisp dialect) so when I come across them in CL I know what they are, but in CL I see from my answers on SO that I use `aux` or `test-aux` inside a global function called `test`.